# VS 2017 error: "Attempted TextBuffer edit operation while another edit is in progress"

Tags: visual-studio

As the title suggests, I often get the error when I try to edit code after running the program. I have to restart VS to make it work again.

Any other solution?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Closing and opening the file again should resolve the issue.This may be caused by an extension or may be `"ActivityLog.xml"` is lock to write by other process. Don't need to restart VS just current file.

Comment: Using vs2019 in Dec 2021 It worked but randomly some code is missing/removed in the file.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have the text:

```
@(@*refs.tipo + " - " +*@ (refs.tipo == "I" ? "Investigando" : "Encerrado"))
```

I replaced it with:

```
@((refs.tipo == "I" ? "Investigando" : "Encerrado"))
```

And it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was trying to edit a comment in a .cshtml in VS 2019 `@**@` and whit the second character inside the comment the error popped up, so I had to write it first and then comment it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).